# OpenApi 3 : validate string query param

Tags: regex, swagger, openapi

I'm building a rest API.
With query params like this : `/?param1=value1&param2=...`

My params are `string` and must be not `null`. `""`, `" "` or `"   "` are not accepted either.

I tried something like this :

```
schema:
    type: string
    pattern: '^(?!\s*$).+'
```

But it does not work. I guess `""` is considered as not empty because it is made of two characters.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew but this is exactly what I proposed

Comment: Please explain what you mean by does not work

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I test something like this : /?param1="" I should expect an error because param1 has no value. But I didnt have any error

Comment: Do you mean input validation in Swagger UI? Or validations in server-side code generated from your API definition? Or something else?

Comment: I just used ^\w+$